# C# update statement with extract

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

I get error message :

> IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)

I think in the code is not any variable that needs `[]` or?

I was searching and everybody has something to do with `[]`.

```
string queryString = "SELECT sum(skupaj) FROM cas where sifra = " + textBox1.Text + " and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Datum) = "+textBox2.Text+"";

try                                                             
{
            OleDbConnection conn = GetConnection();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, conn);
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ure = reader.GetValue(0).ToString(); ;

            }
            reader.Close();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: I'd read up on SQL Injection.  Your code could be vulnerable if someone entered a `;DROP TABLE cas` in TextBox2 for example.

Comment: I know that, but that is not the point, I need that query working.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want a sum of something, you dont need a datareader. simply do this:

```
 try                                                             
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = GetConnection();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, conn);
            conn.Open();
            int count = (Int32) command.ExecuteScalar();
            conn.Close();    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the table name inside a square bracket like [CAS]. This kind of problem happens if you are using a reserved word in ODBC sql or you are using a field that has space in between then you have to put the field inside a pair of ticks like 'field name'.

Comment: I am assuming you are using oracle, right? Try to get the actual value from your query string like for example using debug. And run it in Oracle and see if it works. If not then try to correct it in Oracle before transporting it back to your code.

Comment: Ok, but again check again your original Query if it has no reserved words in MS Access check here : http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx Or it could be that your Textboxes itself so put a square bracket in your sql string like : sifra = [" + textBox1.Text + "]"